# dynamically added onclick event to anchor tag, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the below anchor tag in my jsp

```
<a href="javascript:submit(this)">save</a>
<a href="javascript:alert(this)">something</a>
```

I require to stop the default, href behaviour and yet have these functions called at onclick. For the same i have written this piece of code:

```
$('a[href^=\'#\']').live("click", function (e) {
   alert("I am being called #");
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
      $("a[href^='javascript']").each(function(){
            alert("replacing");
            var w=$(this).attr('href');

            $(this).attr('href','#');

            $(this).attr("onclick",w);
   });
});
```

However, the functions are not being called on clicking the links. Could you please tell me where I am going wrong. I am using IE 8.

Comment: "Where am I going wrong? I am using IE 8." - there.

Comment: @H2CO3 haha. -- have you tried 'onclick=function()' ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make the href="#" and onclick="submit(this)" in your initial markup?  The "onclick" doesn't need/want the "javascript:" prefix like href does...I would be that's the root of your issue.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to attach the click handler before the anchor with `href="#"' exists. Also, `.live()` is deprecated. Use `.on()` instead.

Comment: @ryan.. i cant change the intial markup, as that already exists in many places in my code, and it would need a lot of time to manually update

Comment: @jfrj could you please explain how to make the changes

Comment: See my answer below .. similar to what jfrj is suggesting.

Comment: `where I am going wrong` ??? you're using IE8 !!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[href^=\'#\']",function (e) {
   alert("I am being called #");
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});

$(document).ready(function(){    
      $("a[href^='javascript']").attr('href','#');    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  var aTag = document.createElement('a');
  aTag.setAttribute('href', "#");
  aTag.setAttribute('id', "tagId");
  aTag.innerHTML = "link text";

  mydiv.appendChild(aTag);

  $("#tagId").on('click', function(e) {
    alert(1)

  });
});
```